# Not able to use maven jacoco offline mode to calculate UT coverage with mockito @Spy annotation

Tags: java, mockito, sonarqube, jacoco

does jacoco offline mode support the mockito `@Spy` annotation? I've tested several rounds and jacoco report is not able to get the coverage(always 0.0%) when I use the mockito `@Spy`:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
class SampleTest {
  @Spy
  @InjectMocks
  private ServiceImpl impl;
  
   @BeforeEach
  void initMock() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
  }
  
  @Test
  void testWithException() throws Exception {
    impl.testExcep();
  }
}
```

maven pom:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.jacoco.agent</artifactId>
        <version>0.8.6</version>
        <classifier>runtime</classifier>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    
    
    //.. plugins
    
     <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>0.8.6</version>
                    <executions>
      <execution>
                            <id>default-instrument</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>instrument</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>default-report</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>report</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <dataFile>${project.build.directory}/jacoco.exec</dataFile>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>test</phase>
                            <id>default-restore-instrumented-classes</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>restore-instrumented-classes</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <configuration>
                        <includes>com/test/**/*.class</includes>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
```

The jacoco agent is not able to get the coverage report for impl.testExcep();, I also checked with faq, does it indeed not support the @Spy annotation?

I also found another answer: https://groups.google.com/g/jacoco/c/Yf4QsxcpDfY

Please help me to see this question, thanks so much.

Comment: Could you explain what do you mean about "offline"?

Comment: Do you get coverage without `@Spy`?